# redirect the user to specific page based on select tag by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom, authentication

I'm trying to redirect the user based on select HTML tag by javascript I also need to set the word admin for both user and password?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ukJq.png)

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
 var i = x.selectedIndex;

 if (x.options[i].text === "Building 1") {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building1/";
 } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 2") {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building2/";
 } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 3") {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building3/";
 } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 4") {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building4/";
 } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 5") {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building5/";
 } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 6") {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building6/";
 } else {
  window.location.href = "../../realview/Building7/";
 }
}
```

```html
<input id="user" class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="User">
<input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">

       <select id="mySelect" class="login100-form" >
        <option value="Building 1">Building 1</option>
        <option value="Building 2">Building 2</option>
        <option value="Building 3">Building 3</option>
        <option value="Building 4">Building 4</option>
        <option value="Building 5">Building 5</option>
        <option value="Building 6">Building 6</option>
        <option value="Building 7">Building 7</option>
      </select>

      <div  class="container-login100-form-btn" onclick="myFunction()" >
       <!-- <a href="" target="blank" class="login100-form-btn"  > -->
        <button type="button" class="login100-form-btn"  >
         Login
        </button>        
       </a>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
     var i = x.selectedIndex;

     if (x.options[i].text === "Building 1") {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building1/";
     } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 2") {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building2/";
     } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 3") {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building3/";
     } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 4") {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building4/";
     } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 5") {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building5/";
     } else if (x.options[i].text === "Building 6") {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building6/";
     } else {
      window.location.href = "../../realview/Building7/";
     }
    }
function select(){
document.getElementById('user').value="admin";
document.getElementById('password').value="admin";
}
```

```html
User:<input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
           <select onchange="select()" id="mySelect" class="login100-form" >
            <option value="Building 1">Building 1</option>
            <option value="Building 2">Building 2</option>
            <option value="Building 3">Building 3</option>
            <option value="Building 4">Building 4</option>
            <option value="Building 5">Building 5</option>
            <option value="Building 6">Building 6</option>
            <option value="Building 7">Building 7</option>
          </select>

          <div  class="container-login100-form-btn" onclick="myFunction()" >
           <!-- <a href="" target="blank" class="login100-form-btn"  > -->
            <button type="button" class="login100-form-btn"  >
             Login
            </button>        
           </a>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code `function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var i = x.selectedIndex;
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
var passInput = document.getElementById("passInput").value;

if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 1" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building1/";
} else if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 2" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building2/";
} else if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 3" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building3/";
} else if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 4" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building4/";
} else if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 5" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building5/";
} else if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 6" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building6/";
} else if (
    x.options[i].text === "Building 7" &&
    userInput === "admin" &&
    passInput === "admin"
) {
    window.location.href = "../../realview/Building7/";
} else {
    alert("There is something error in your login information");
}
```

}
`